# How to calculate the quantity of different size of tiles to fit rectangle area

Tags: area, tiling

Let's say I have 3 type of tiles in option. (Width x Height)

1. Tile A = 30x30 cm
2. Tile B = 30x40 cm
3. Tile C = 60x60 cm

I want to fit rectangle area of 70x100 cm

How to calculate the quantity of each tile to fit the rectangle area by using the biggest tile first and fill the rest with the smaller ones.

Clarifications:

1. Use the biggest tiles to cover most of area as many as possible
   (without cutting it)
2. The smaller ones will fit the rest of area (without cutting it)
3. The rest of area that smaller than dimension of the smallest tile will be sum up and use the smallest one to fill (cut smallest one)
4. The above is just an example problem.
5. The location of each tile (if possible)
6. Tiles can be rotated

[image: Example of answer]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to make it clearer. Do you want to use the most tiles, or cover the largest fraction of the area? What does priority mean? If you could cover more with some small tiles instead of big ones would that be OK? Do you want a solution to this particular problem or is this just an example? So you need to know how to place the tiles, or just how many? If possible, show us some answers with pictures.

Comment: @EthanBolker I just added more information in my question. I'll try to make a picture to make it more clear.

Comment: Image answer added